# How to make a Python program handle a here document?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I've written a Python wrapper (pyprog) to run a program (someprogram), something like this:

```
...do some setup stuff in Python...
print("run [y=yes]")
CHOICE=input()
...do some setup stuff in Python...
if CHOICE == "y":
  status=subprocess.call(["someprogram"])
  sys.exit(status)
```

A user wants to use a shell script to run the program and feed it input using a here document like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
pyprog > pyprog.log << EOF
y
file1
file2
EOF
```

Is there a way to spawn the subprocess so that the here document will work (the "y" gets consumed by the Python input(), and the "file1" and "file2" continue along as stdin to someprogram)?  Right now, the Python input() takes the "y", but the rest of it disappears.

Comment: What does "work" mean here?  What exactly does not work with your current solution?

Comment: Are you trying to pass the here document into the subprocess?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to pass the here document into the subprocess.  Right now, the whole thing terminates because "someprogram" does not get the input "file1" and "file2".

Comment: Arg...OK, I just realised that I was doing something in my Python script that was affecting this (and I didn't mention it).  The Python script has a query in it that messes this up - going to edit the original question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to connect `sys.stdin` to the `stdin` of the call.

```
status=subprocess.call(["someprogram"], stdin=sys.stdin)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
status=subprocess.call(["someprogram"], stdin=sys.stdin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this a few times before:  https://gist.github.com/887225

Basically it's a python script that accepts a number of command line parameters, performs some transformation based on what was input, then uses os.system() to evoke a shell command. 
 In this example I'm calling Java, passing in a class path then running the ProgramName.jar program.